# react button is called before onPress when using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to request an `API` `request` using hooks. But my problem is that my function is called before I `onPress`.

I have an custom API component like this:

```
const FetchDataPut = (URL) => {

  useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
          const res = await axios({
                    method: 'put',
                    url: URL,
                    data:{
                      name:'111',
                      email:'222',
                      password:'333',
                      id:'444',
                      phone:'555'
                    }
                  });
          const response = await res;
          console.log(response, 'completed')
      }
      fetchData()
  },[])
  return null
}
```

I could see from the `console.log` that api request has `completed`. My problem is that my `api component` is called before I onPress the button.

This is my Button component:

```
const EditAccount = (props) => {

  const Desktop = () => {
    const URL = `MyURL...`
    return (
      <View>
        <Button title='edit account' onPress={FetchDataPut(URL)}/>
      </View>
    )
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Desktop/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If I change my `onPress` function to an arrow function like this:
`onPress={()=>FetchDataPut(URL)}` component isn't called before I `onPress` it. But it will give me an error `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`

Any Idea how to my the api request when I `onPress` the `Button` ?

Any comments or advice would be really helpful. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to go is to use a hook rather than a component:

```
const useFetchDataPut = () => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!url) return;

        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await axios({
                method: "put",
                url,
                data: {
                    name: "111",
                    email: "222",
                    password: "333",
                    id: "444",
                    phone: "555"
                }
            });
            const response = await res;
            console.log(response, "completed");
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [url]);

    return setUrl;
};
```

And then call it when you press the button. Also `Desktop` should be defined outside of the `EditAccount` component.

```
const Desktop = () => {
    const setUrl = useFetchDataPut();

    return (
        <View>
            <Button
                title="edit account"
                onPress={() => setUrl("https://...")}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const EditAccount = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Desktop />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ill try it this out and let you know :)

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if you need further explanation

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

You’re setting the onPress prop to *the result of calling FetchDataPut(URL)*. The prop should be the function itself, not the result of invoking it. By using an arrow function you’re declaring a new function that, when invoked, calls FetchDataPut.

If you’re invoking it on button press, there’s no need for it to be a hook.

Also, FetchDataPut isn’t a React component.

Declare your data fetching function by itself:

```js
async function fetchData(url) {
  return axios({
    method: 'put',
    url: URL,
    data: {
       name:'111',
       email:'222',
       password:'333',
       id:'444',
       phone:'555'
     }
  })
}
```

And then invoke it on button press.

```
const handler = async function ( ) {
  // or just inline the axios request right here
  // instead of declaring a separate function for it. 
  const result = await fetchData(url);

  // do something with the result
}
```

```
<Button onPress={handler} />
```

Apologies for the frequent edits. Trying to do this from my phone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer your solution works well. I wish I could accept 2 answers but @Alvaro answer is more suitable for my situation. Anyway really appreciated it!